# Using javascript to edit class (not inline styles on elements)

Tags: javascript, css, styles

I don't thikn that this is possible but I want your input anyway.
Lets say that I have a style like this:

```
<style>
  .something{
    height : 100px;
  }
</style>
```

and then my HTML looks like this:

```
<ul>
  <li class="something">1</li>
  <li class="something">2</li>
  <li class="something">3</li>
</ul>
```

Now I want to change the value "height" in the class ".something", not set new heights of the `<li>` elements. If i set the style on the elements and then add more `<li>` elements they will have the original height of the class ".something"

---

What I want to do is let the user add `<li>` elements and select height of all the elements.
I know I can set them with javascript and just remember to set new `<li>` elements when they're added, but it would be convenient if I somehow could change:

```
<style>
  .something{
    height : 100px;
  }
</style>
```

to e.g.

```
<style>
  .something{
    height : 85px;
  }
</style>
```

using javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better place a identity (attribute, id, name) on the style element, so you can target the particular style (DOM) element (will be helpfull when there are many), and then replacethe inner html
eg:

```
<style id="targetStyle">
  .something{
    height : 100px;
  }
</style>
```

and then in your javascript

```
var styleDom = document.getElementById('targetStyle');
styleDom.innerHTML = styleDom.innerHTML.replace(/height.*px;/,'height: 85px;');
```

Build the Regex properly according to your use case, its just a rough example to describe on the part how you can achive this, instead how to replace a string in depth.

Comment: Hey..  You're right..  I feel stupid I didn't even consider the <style> element to be editable just like any other element.